# Connect phone and computer android

Tags: android, sockets

So, i want to make an android application who works like a remote, so i can execute a command from my android app on my computer. So far i have looked a the Socket framework, and it works fine if the server and client is on the same computer, but if i move the client to my phone i get the error, that the host can't be found. I'm pretty sure it is something about how i connect, but i have no clue, how to solve it. Is it possible to connect to my computer from my phone via a Socket, if they are on same wifi-network?

Edit:
Sorry, thought i had linked. I have just been trying to make the java tutorial on the subject working.

### Client:  KnockKnockClient.java

```
public class KnockKnockClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Socket kkSocket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            kkSocket = new Socket("taranis", 4444);
            out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: taranis.");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: taranis.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String fromServer;
        String fromUser;

        while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Server: " + fromServer);
            if (fromServer.equals("Bye."))
                break;

            fromUser = stdIn.readLine();
        if (fromUser != null) {
                System.out.println("Client: " + fromUser);
                out.println(fromUser);
        }
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
        stdIn.close();
        kkSocket.close();
    }
}
```

### Server:KnockKnockServer.java

```
public class KnockKnockServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 4444.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Accept failed.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine, outputLine;
        KnockKnockProtocol kkp = new KnockKnockProtocol();

        outputLine = kkp.processInput(null);
        out.println(outputLine);

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
             outputLine = kkp.processInput(inputLine);
             out.println(outputLine);
             if (outputLine.equals("Bye."))
                break;
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    }
}
```

I followed [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) tutorial.

Comment: there is but as you say it's `something about how i connect`, kindly post your code so that you can be helped

Comment: There you go, sorry about that!

Comment: Does your android phone knows what ip "taranis" is?

Comment: No, I haven't put any information about ip, because I'm not sure how.